# Code not terminating and keeps looking for input

Tags: python-3.x

for an input like

Courses
TRAN~Transfiguration~1~2011-2012~Minerva McGonagall
CHAR~Charms~1~2011-2012~Filius Flitwick
Students
SLY2301~Hannah Abbott
SLY2302~Euan Abercrombie
SLY2303~Stewart Ackerley
SLY2304~Bertram Aubrey
SLY2305~Avery
SLY2306~Malcolm Baddock
SLY2307~Marcus Belby
SLY2308~Katie Bell
SLY2309~Sirius Orion Black
EndOfInput

my code keeps looking for input. Why?

```
info= []
line= input()
while(True):
      while line!='Students':
            line=input()
      if line=='Students':
            line=input()
            while line!='EndOfInput':
                  info.append(line.split('~'))
                  line=input()
      elif line=='EndOfInput':
          break
      else:
          break
print(info)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just look at this portion of your code.

```
while line!='EndOfInput':
              info.append(line.split('~'))
              line=input()
```

Sorry to say but this is really bad writing. You can replace this with

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    info.append(line.split('~'))
```

Using this, until the user presses **ctrl + d**, it will take input from user and append it to the **info** list.